# What's the best extension to make firefox' home page look like chrome's?

Tags: firefox, browser, browser-addons

What's the best extension to make firefox' home page look like chrome's? I'm specifically interested in the shortcuts for the most visited websites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Speed Dial](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4810) extension lets you add thumbnails for whichever shortcuts you want (I don't think Chrome can do this), but it won't arrange them by usage count.

[New Tab King](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10828) will list the most-recently used sites, closed tabs, and suggested sites; but it doesn't show thumbnails for the pages.

The closest thing to Chrome's layout is [Jump Start](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/8914)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you install the [Google Toolbar](http://toolbar.google.com/) for Firefox, you can enable the "[new tab page](http://www.google.com/support/toolbar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=115561)" feature.

Comment: Thanks! I chose the other answer, though, because I don't want a toolbar :)

Comment: Well, you can hide the toolbar :)

Answer (score 1):

While not quite the same, I use Taboo to provide thumbnailed shortcuts, and have this Taboo page set as my homepage. The key difference is that you decide on the Taboo links - it doesn't calculate the most popular links, so it's similar in UI if not quite the same in practice.

Personally, I prefer this to Chrome because the links are fixed - I find it slightly annoying in Chrome knowing that a given link will be on the front page, but not quite sure what position it is in.

YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Foxtab firefox addon](http://techx64.com/foxtab-firefox-addon/), you can add website thumbnails of your favourite sites to homepage and also shuffle tabs in 3-D. It features a lot of customizations.

Answer (score -1):

Two customizable firefox start/home page:
(Update, note to avoid down vote: they aren't like chrome, but are superior solutions if you want to choose what's displayed)

**Extension [Desktop](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/11781)**:
Features:

- Add thumbnails to new tabs
- Align them by drag&drop
- Create sub-folders
- Sync layout using extensions like XMarks or Weave
- Add your own search engines*

(*I use many search engines with [Add to Search Bar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3682) & [Organize Search Engines](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4565))

[image]

**Web site: [Symbaloo](http://www.symbaloo.com/fr/)**

[image]